# Cloud firestore security rule allow creation only by authenticated user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a posts collection which holds posts documents of this structure:

```
{
 title: "test title"
 ...
 authorUid: "testuid"
}
```

I wanted to add a security rule which only allows an authenticated user with a uid to add a document to this collection with the same authoUid.

I tried something this -

```
match /posts/{postId} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow create: if signedInUserIsPostAuthor();
}

function signedInUserIsPostAuthor(){
   return request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.authorUid;
}
```

but this seems to fail. I was assuming that the authenticated user (request.auth.uid) should be equal to the document before write (request.resource.data).

But this isn't working. Any clue what I am missing ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the (minimum) actual code that fails? Please also ensure that the code proves that the rules are being met, so for example: log the current user, and that you're writing their UID in `authorUid`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it worked perfectly. I have attached a screenshot.

Possible solution.

1. Confirm spelling errors on authorUid
2. Print authorUid
3. Print currentUser.uid

Firebase is saying that no 2 and 3 above do not have the same value. What I can confirm is that your rules are correct.

> I was assuming that the authenticated user (request.auth.uid) should be equal to the document before write (request.resource.data).

**Yes**

[image]